# Is there a way to create locale dependent routing in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a website, on Symfony2, translated to few languages (for example en, de, ru, pl). Every language version is set up on it's own server, so I have server for english version, other for russian etc. each have locale set to that language version. I also need to have routing translated to that language, so I'm using https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle and it almost do what I want. Problems starts when there are "colissions" in translation, for example German version have route /kontakt and Polish varsion have route /kontakt, but routing will always "catch" the route that is configured first and change my webiste language to it. For example if I have:

```
contact:
    locales:  { de: "/kontakt", pl: "/kontakt" }
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Frontend:contact }
```

I'll always be redirected to German version of the website and locale will be changed to de (and every link will be generated for German version).

Since I have every language version onit's own server is there a way to force symfony to use only the routes for one language version? 
Maybe there is a better way to configure whole routing all together in my situation?

Comment: Do you have any "prefix" for your sites? Example: `http://yourdomain.com/de/`, `http://yourdomain.com/en/`, `http://yourdomain.com/pl` and so on?

Comment: No, I have every version on it's own domain for example http://domain.pl, http://domain.de, http://domain.com

Comment: To manage multidomain website I always use the excellent [multisite-bundle](https://github.com/alexandresalome/multisite-bundle)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say that but it seems that locales per domain feature is not implemented in that bundle, i refer you to that issue :

https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle/issues/19

Comment: Maybe there is some other bundle I can use or some other way to do it?